# Wordpress : Shift from local MySQL to Amazon RDS Mysql?

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, wordpress, ubuntu-12.04, amazon-rds

i have a 32 bit Bitnami ubuntu wordpress stack ami for amazon and hence a working wordpress installation. My questions are

1)How can i shift over to amazon RDS mysql from local MySQL. And if more than one what would what would be the easiest way to shift over to amazon RDS from the local mysql (with probably the least effort  ).

2)Secondly after shifting over to amazon RDS would it be a safe option to uninstall mysql as i wouldnt be requiring it and would save me a considerable amount of memory?

Edit: the ec2 instance running the bitmani stack and RDS are from same account and same AWS region and RDS is enabled to ec2 security group.
P.S> for those who dont know what bitnami stack is : in this case its jut a pre configured ubuntu installation with all required components to run wordpress preinstalled. Furthermore even worpdress comes preinstalled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you read this article http://aws.amazon.com/rds/mysql/ ? As far as I understand it should be easy as a piece of cake, you should dump your db and restore to mysql in rds. http://aws.amazon.com/articles/2933 - this is a good howto

Comment: thank you the second article solved my problem . The main thing i was concerned for was that is there a risk that my website might break while porting to rds but as it turns out using command line i can avoid that risk and as soon as dabase is exported to rds all i have to do is change database details to the ones of rds in wp-config and i am good to go :)
thanks